# Correlation analyses among three variables in R

Tags: r

I made a 3D scatterplot with three parameters. Is there any way to get the statistic results such as R2 and p-value by using R? Thank you.

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of the code you've used to get this scatterplot.

Can you expand on what you mean? Scatterplots dont have R2 and p-values. Are you also fitting a model to your data? Can you include that code?

Comment: data(iris)
head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I just wonder is it possible to obtain a correlation equation, r2 and p from a 3D scatterplot? Thank you again!

Comment: Not from the plot, but from the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a reproducible example when requesting help. Here is a simple example:

```
library(Hmisc)
set.seed(42)
X <- matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
# rcorr(X)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  1.00 -0.37  0.44
# [2,] -0.37  1.00 -0.15
# [3,]  0.44 -0.15  1.00
# 
# n= 10 
# 
# 
# P
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,]        0.2857 0.2031
# [2,] 0.2857        0.6723
# [3,] 0.2031 0.6723
```

Comment: data(iris)
head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

Comment: `rcorr(iris[, -5])`